Magento 2 Class not found error
I  try to install this module modele in my Magento 2.4.6 store.
https://github.com/scriptbaker/magento2-ship-out-of-stock-items?tab=readme-ov-file
The module is installed fine and is activated.
But keeping getting this error when try to ship a order.
I have try  all upgrade commands, and clean and make static content, but still getting error.
Error: Class "Scriptbaker\ShipOutofStockItems\Observer\AlwaysShipOrder" not found in /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#1 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#2 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Event/ObserverFactory.php(36): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#3 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverFactory->get()
#4 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(65): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch()
#5 /var/www/html/magento245_final/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(710): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch()
#7 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(390): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->beforeSave()
#8 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save()
#9 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->___callParent()
#10 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 /var/www/html/magento245_final/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Shipment/Interceptor.php(77): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#12 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(663): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->save()
#13 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#14 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->___callParent()
#15 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/html/magento245_final/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#17 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Transaction.php(134): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Interceptor->save()
#18 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php(95): Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction->save()
#19 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php(168): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save->_saveShipment()
#20 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save->execute()
#21 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callParent()
#22 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#23 /var/www/html/magento245_final/generated/code/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#24 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#25 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#26 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch()
#27 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callParent()
#28 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(145): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#29 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
#30 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#31 /var/www/html/magento245_final/generated/code/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#32 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->dispatch()
#33 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#34 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#35 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#36 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#37 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#38 /var/www/html/magento245_final/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#39 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#40 /var/www/html/magento245_final/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#41 /var/www/html/magento245_final/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#42 /var/www/html/magento245_final/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#43 {main}


It's working fine for me, no error's while creating shipment.
